# TypeORM is duplicating my post when I run the command | CQRS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, cqrs, node.js-typeorm

I'm using CQRS and TypeORM in nestJs for create an user, orders and products application.

I have these entities in typeorm and when I run the command for create an user, I get an error that email is duplicated, when check the Database found out that there is 2 users with different id but one of them is empty. I don't know what's happening.

UserEntity:

```
@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @Column({unique: true})
    email!: string;

    @Column()
    password!: string;

    @Column()
    name!: string;

    @Column()
    role!: string;
    
    @OneToMany(type => OrderEntity, order => order.userId)
    orders?: OrderEntity[] | any;

    @OneToMany(type => ItemEntity, item => item.userId)
    items?: ItemEntity[] | any;
}
```

OrderEntity:

```
@Entity()
export class OrderEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @Column()
    buyerName!: string;

    @Column()
    buyerPhone!: number;

    @Column()
    buyerEmail!: string;

    @Column()
    shippingMethod!: string;

    @Column()
    shippingAddress!: string;

    @Column()
    shippingCity!: string;

    @Column()
    shippingRegion!: string;

    @Column()
    shippingCountry!: string;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    creationDate!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    pack_promise_min!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    pack_promise_max!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    ship_promise_min!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    ship_promise_max!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    delivery_promise_min!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    delivery_promise_max!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    ready_pickup_promise_min!: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
    ready_pickup_promise_max!: Date;

    @Column()
    status!: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.orders)
    userId: UserEntity | any;

    @ManyToMany(type => ItemEntity, item => item.id, { cascade: true })
    @JoinTable({ name: 'orders_items'})
    items: ItemEntity[];
}
```

ItemEntity:

```
@Entity()
export class ItemEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @Column()
    name!: string;

    @Column()
    qty!: string;

    @Column()
    weight!: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.items)
    userId!: UserEntity | any;

    @ManyToMany((type => OrderEntity), order => order.id, {cascade: true})
    orders?: OrderEntity[]
}
```

All this is happening since I declared the relations, I think the problem is there.

This happened in the database:

[image]

Comment: Please provide with a data used to create a User and the service layer function implementation that is responsible for saving User record in database. We are lacking details to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer it's too stupid like me xD. I was making a console.log on the controller, just for see some of information, and the command execute itself two times. Sorry, my mistake.